# Does Apple or/and Google store allow Web View App (including Login and Payment Gateway) with Push-Notification feature?

Tags: webview, push-notification, google-play, app-store, payment-gateway

I want to publish an app which contains a WebView (with Login, Payment Gateway) and push-Notification. The web is online programme for Smoke Quitting. We need to address both B2B and B2C segments, therefore we need integrate payment gateway due to different pricing. Does Apple / Google allow it?

Answer (score 2):

@Daniel, This question has a very broad scope and pointers to be explained because **Google Play Store** and **Apple App Store** has different app review guidelines. In short we can conclude it very briefly as follows:

---

**Google Play Store( Android OS):**

Google Play Store is not tough with the app publishing guidelines/ minimal app functionality. You can have the Android app with mentioned functionalities.

Even your app will be available in 5-6 hours after you will publish your app.

---

**Apple App Store( iOS):**

[Apple Review Guideline - 4.2 | app minimal functionality](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality)

[Apple Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Apple is very concerned about app's significance on app store like it should not copy of other app and it should have some minimum functionality( excluding push notification, location feature etc.).

So you should go with the more functionalities or you should go for iOS native functionality rather than just web view. App review takes approximately 1-5 days to get approved/rejected.

> *According to Apple:*
>
> *If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn't provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, or is just plain creepy, it may not be accepted.*